# PostgreSQL query takes a long time (as it's not using the index)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-12

This query takes a long time, as I guess it's doing a full-table scan. It works ok in Oracle, just not in Postgres 12.

```
select count(*)
FROM EVENT 
WHERE PK_EVENT > (select CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT FROM SYSTEM_CONTROL)
```

If however, I run this one, it comes back in seconds.

```
select count(*)
FROM EVENT 
WHERE PK_EVENT > (1000755073)
```

Both the *PK_EVENT* & *CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT* columns are defined as "int8", as they could get very large. *EVENT.PK_EVENT* is the primary key. I've tried re-arranging the query, but so far nothing works. The count(*) only results in 2537 rows i.e. the number of rows generated today on our test Pg database.

Query plans :

using system_control:-

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2909961.80..2909961.81 rows=1 width=8)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Seq Scan on system_control  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Gather  (cost=2909960.58..2909960.79 rows=2 width=8)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Params Evaluated: $0
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2908960.58..2908960.59 rows=1 width=8)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..2866882.04 rows=16831415 width=0)
                    Filter: (pk_event > $0)
JIT:
  Functions: 8
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

using hardcoded value:-

```
Aggregate  (cost=11.42..11.43 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Index Only Scan using event_pkey on event  (cost=0.57..11.36 rows=25 width=0)
        Index Cond: (pk_event > 1000755073)
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire query is planned up front, and at the time of planning it doesn't know what value will be found in CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT.  It makes the generic assumption that the inequality will match 1/3 of the rows, which is obviously quite wrong.  When faced with this situation, I usually just have the client software run the queries separately, stuffing the result of one into a parameter for the other, assuming I can tolerate the prospect that the value may have changed between the two executions.

That said, it should probably be doing an index only scan anyway.  Do you have a very high setting for random_page_cost?  What are you other planner settings?  Has the table EVENT been vacuumed recently?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the **EXPLAIN** so we can see what's going on under the hood. What if your re-wrote your query like this logical equivalent, does it make any difference?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM EVENT E
INNER JOIN SYSTEM_CONTROL S
    ON E.PK_EVENT > S.CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT
```

Comment: Nope, that still takes a long-time (been running for >5minutes now and not completed). Query plans added to my original question.

Comment: Interesting, yea this `Parallel Seq Scan` seems to be your issue. Not sure how to resolve it at the moment.

Comment: Interesting if I wrap the into a stored function, it does the query in a sensible time .... select pkg_util.f_count_events_beteen_dates(CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT)
from system_control

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found thus far that is performant, is to put the inner query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EVENT E WHERE PK_EVENT > (arg)" into a stored function and then pass in the id from the SYSTEM_CONTROL. Thank you for the other suggestions :)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the * there is no use of index (apart from the PK). The subquery isn't using a `WHERE` clause so is doing a full table/index scan on `SYSTEM_CONTROL`

If you only want to get the number of rows you can change to this code

```
select count(PK_EVENT)
FROM EVENT 
WHERE PK_EVENT > (select CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT FROM SYSTEM_CONTROL)
```

To improve the above query you can create a nonclustered index on EVENT table using the PK_EVENT (in case this isn't the PK of that table already)
Also please provide the output of the `EXPLAIN` command:

```
EXPLAIN select count(PK_EVENT)
    FROM EVENT 
    WHERE PK_EVENT > (select CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT FROM SYSTEM_CONTROL)
```

Maybe you can try with this CTE:

```
WITH SYSTEM_CONTROL_CTE (CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT )
AS
(SELECT CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT  
 FROM   SYSTEM_CONTROL)
SELECT Count(E.PK_EVENT)
FROM   SYSTEM_CONTROL_CTE as SC 
    ,EVENT as E 
WHERE E.PK_EVENT > SC.CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT
```

Comment: When using the **aggregate function** `COUNT()` there's usually no difference between counting `*` and counting `SomeField` as it's syntactical sugar in most **RDBMS**, and the optimizer is smart enough to know when to use an index, as is the case in the execution plan of OP's second example.

Comment: If I try your suggestion of "select count(PK_EVENT).....", I get the same result, i.e. a very slow query.

Comment: I will disagree with you on that. That will be true only if you didn't have a where clause, but this is not the case

Comment: I disagree with your disagree as the query has been running for approx 15 minutes now..(select count(PK_EVENT)
FROM EVENT 
WHERE PK_EVENT > (select CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT FROM SYSTEM_CONTROL), if I use a hardcoded value, it returns in <2 seconds.

Comment: The issue is on table SYSTEM_CONTROL, how much record does it have?

Comment: Only 1 row (it's a system control table)

Comment: Maybe try with a CTE for example this:

WITH SYSTEM_CONTROL_CTE (CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT )
AS
(SELECT CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT  
 FROM   SYSTEM_CONTROL)
SELECT Count(E.PK_EVENT)
FROM   SYSTEM_CONTROL_CTE as SC 
 ,EVENT as E 
WHERE E.PK_EVENT > SC.CHECKPOINT1_PKEVENT

Comment: Been running for 15 minutes thus far, so unfortunately doesn't seem to help. As mentioned above, moving the (select count(*) FROM EVENT) into a stored function, has.